# Raspberry Pi 2 B GPIO Native C library

Tags: c, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I have recently ordered a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B but after doing some research I am unsure whether or not it comes with a native C library for the GPIO. I have seen that there are several 3rd party libraries such as WiringPi, but I would've preferred to use a native one if it exists. [This](http://codeandlife.com/2015/03/25/raspberry-pi-2-vs-1-gpio-benchmark/) website seems to indicate that it does exist.

**Edit**: By native, I mean a library that comes out of the box with the Pi, either was officially implemented by the Foundation or Linux on release of the product or at least has very low-level access to the pins, and has been thoroughly tested on this model.

Comment: It works out-of-the-box IIRC.

Comment: It is a Linux porting...

Comment: It's quite unclear ... it seems the benchmark's "native C library" means "do it yourself in the test code", whereas the bcm test (in [strobe_bcm.c](https://github.com/jokkebk/rpi-gpio-benchmark/blob/master/strobe_bcm.c)) uses what I would calla "native C library". Confusing.

Comment: The pi uses memory-mapped I/O. You can use the macros like in @unwind 's link or mmap /dev/mem and use the mmapped area  : http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples (setup_io() : at the bottom)

Comment: I'm not even sure what "native" means in this context.  Pretty much *all* of the software on your raspberry pi is "third-party" software.  That's the nature of open source operating system distributions.

Comment: @larsks it means it has been thoroughly tested on this model at least...

Comment: Selecting the github link of linked page you can reach to [THIS](https://github.com/jokkebk/rpi-gpio-benchmark/blob/master/strobe.c) where you can see how to drive a gpio using standard linux functions.

Comment: @Æðelstan That's a really strange interpretation of "native", and you should edit it into your question for clarity.

Comment: Use WiringPi. Use WiringPi. Use WiringPi.

Comment: "Out of the box," the RPi comes with a first-stage boot-loader, and not much else.